# Devise does double 401 with redirect after timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 with Devise 2.1.2.

If a session times out while the user is still in the app, the next time the user clicks something in the app, it redirects to the signin page.  However, the value of `session[:user_return_to]` is often not what I would expect. In trying to track down the cause, I found that Devise (or Warden) is doing *two* `GET`s after receiving a 401 error.

For example, if the user is editing a user and clicks on **Update** after the session timeout, the log looks like this:

```
Started PUT "/users/9f276de6-2175-11e3-b8ce-01413834ba1d" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 16:43:36 -0700
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"+JP3qXGyUEodmmlLQtpOJpxF8JuEg5sp4Iyjit784Ms=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>...}
  User Load (1.5ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = '9b5f6b2e-40bc-31e3-b199-0141337836d6' LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 9ms

Started GET "/users/9f276de6-2175-11e3-b8ce-01413834ba1d" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 16:43:36 -0700
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9f276de6-2175-11e3-b8ce-01413834ba1d"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms

Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 16:43:36 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (21.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (7.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 174ms (Views: 171.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Where is that first `GET` coming from, i.e. how and why is `#show` getting called after the first authentication failure?

If I could get rid of that first `GET`, I'm hoping `session[:user_return_to]` would remain set to the `/users/{:id}/edit` path, which is probably where the user will want to go after re-authenticating. As it is, `session[:user_return_to]` is set to `/users/{:id}` so they don't go back into edit mode when they log back in.

By the way, even if the failing request is a `GET` rather than a `PUT`, I still see an extra `GET` before it goes to the signin page.

Answer (score 1):

So basically this is bug #2421 reported here:

[store_location!() method gets wrong location after timeout](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2421)

which was addressed by fix #2427:

[redirect user to the referrer if latest request was not GET after timeout](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2427)

As best I can tell, that fix wasn't released until Devise 3.0.0.

**Summary for Future Reference**

Devise 2.1.2 had this routine in **device/failure_app.rb**:

```
def redirect_url
  if warden_message == :timeout
    flash[:timedout] = true
    attempted_path || scope_path
  else
    scope_path
  end
end
```

With that code, the `attempted_path` was set from the PUT request, so the first redirect tried to do a GET on the URI used by the PUT (in this case, `/users/{:id}`).  When used with a GET, that URI invokes the `#show` action.

That code has since been updated to:

```
def redirect_url
  if warden_message == :timeout
    flash[:timedout] = true
    path = if request.get?
      attempted_path
    else
      request.referrer
    end
    path || scope_path
  else
    scope_path
  end
end
```

It looks like that will still do a double-redirect on timeout, but for a PUT, it will use the `request.referrer` (in this case, `/users/{:id}/edit`), so `session[:user_return_to]` should get set correctly.

**Update October 25, 2013**  I've now upgraded to Devise 3.1.1. As expected, a PUT still does two redirects on timeout, but `session[:user_return_to]` is set correctly so the user goes back to the referrer on signin.